# Deriving classes with no virtual destructor in third party software

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

I am given a third-party library with its header to use. Now this library has a class 'Base'. Problem with this class is that it does not have virtual destructor. Now since i don't have the thirds-party code with me i can not do changes over there.

I am told to write few derived classes with this and make sure that the object gets cleaned properly when objects are delete. How can we achieve this?

---

Thanks for reply, looks like i have only 2 options.

1) put virtual destructor in derived class
2) use composition.

I am planning to take approach no 1. I am planning to have wrapper derived class with a virtual destructor. And then use this wrapper derived class for further derivation. Below is the code.

```
//++ THIRD PARTY HEADER
class base
{
public:
    ~base(){ }
};
//-- THIRD PARTY HEADER



//++ MY CODE
// wrapper polymorphic base.
class polymorphic_base
{
public:    
    virtual ~polymorphic_base() { }
};

class derived1 : polymorphic_base
{
/// derived 1
};

class derived2 : polymorphic_base
{
/// derived 2
}


void foo(polymorphic_base *pb)
{
    // use pb
    // use pb
    delete pb;
}


//-- MY CODE
```

Please let me know if this approach should be fine?

Comment: Generally, you're out of luck: if they do not have a virtual destructor, it usually means that the authors of the library do not want you to derive from their class. Why do you need to derive, anyway (as opposed to, say, including an instance as a data member?)

Comment: Just checking: Have you confirmed that `Base` itself it not perhaps derived from some super-base that does have the destructor defined as virtual?

Comment: Who deletes the instance?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight may be you right author do not want this class to be derived. You right, i think i need to change my design and use Base as a composition instead

Answer (score 2):

If the derived class destructor is `public` and non-virtual then it implies that implementor of the third party do not want their class to be used for polymorphic inheritance.

If your implementation plan has an scenario of deleteing a object of derived class pointed to by an base class pointer then the base class not having a `virtual` destructor would lead to an Undefined Behavior.
If your implementation plan does not have above mentioned scenario then you can still derive from the class without any problems.

In the first case, Since you don't have the code for this base class you cannot get over the debacle. Best you can do is consider a `has-a` relationship rather than `is-a` relationship and try to get it working for you.

Answer (score 0):

With the `Base` destructor non-virtual, if you have to support `delete` of `Base*` then you're just out of luck.

Otherwise, to

> “make sure that the object gets cleaned properly when objects are delete”

just add a virtual destructor to your derived class `Derived`.

But are you sure that the requirement is really, literally, "when objects are delete"? Because a much better way forward would be to *prohibit dynamic allocation*. Which you can do in code by making practically unusable something that a `new`-expression needs, such as the allocation function (e.g., restrict its accessibility), and which you can do even more easily by just stating in the documentation that dynamic allocation is not supported.

There might be even better solutions if you could get clarified what the purpose is of having the classes derived from `Base`. Maybe you don't need class derivation. Maybe you can make do with a `Base` member, say.